# Executeing a stored procedure on PL/SQL from Eclipse give "SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000"

Tags: plsql, java-ee-8, eclipse-jee

I have a Java EE app running localy on a Wildfly server and a distant Oracle DB.
Each time i run a Stored Procedure like

```
query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("LGDT_K_UTI_PLM_EXT.P_EXT_CE_TRT");
...
query.execute();
```

I got the error :

```
14:43:38,978 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (default task-5) {call LGDT_K_UTI_PLM_EXT.P_EXT_CE_TRT(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
14:43:39,082 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-5) SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
14:43:39,087 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-5) ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 42 :
PLS-00103: Symbole "1" rencontré à la place d'un des symboles suivants :

   . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <exposant (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or default like
   like2 like4 likec as between from using || indicator multiset
   member submultiset
Symbole "(" a été substitué à "1" pour continuer.
ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 159 :
```

Sorry for French, it just says Symbol "1" found instead of one of following symbols.
The error continues but it repeat the same kind of thing.

The same thing is working fine on the real server of course.
I only get that localy.
I read that it cas come from the case of an empty result. But  I don't really understand why.

Thanks.

Comment: check ur brackets. You have probably lack of a bracket. You didnt provided the full sql code you try to run, so its impossible to say more about exception that you have.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik As I explained in the question it does not work when executed "localy" (through a local Wildfly server). The DB is the same (local app accesses the same DB as distant/production app). So it has nothing to do with the SQL itself, this is the issue...